# VBA UserForm.Image1.Picture won't refresh after Image1.Click calls

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a UserForm that changes pictures when the user changes pages with a SpinButton using:

```
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(imageString)
```

It works fine, but whenever Click() is called on an image, that image ceases to accept any further .Picture changes, even when the routine is empty:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()

End Sub
```

changing pages after calling the empty Click() call will no longer update the Picture. If I add:

```
UserForm.Hide
UserForm.Show
```

or

```
UserForm.Repaint
```

to the page changing routine the .Picture updates will start working again. Why do I have to perform extra actions every time I catch a Click() event, and not when I don't?

Comment: I found that hiding the form and then showing it again on page change fixes it... but why?

Comment: Look into the UserForm.Repaint method

Comment: That does fix it thank you; similar to the hide/show method, added to question. But why is that only necessary after a Click() event?

Comment: Control cosmetic updates are often unreliable. I find it best to do a repaint anytime a control needs a cosmetic update to ensure it happens smoothly